# PHP session not storing

Tags: php, session, nginx

I am using Centos 6.5 with Nginx on Digitalocean.  I am trying to store sessions but it is not storing. I tried on two server both are not working.
This is the simple code i tried.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'true';
?>
```

And the second file:

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

In this second file it should show the sessions but it is showing empty array "array()"

Comment: Can you print the session storage configuration values from the `php.ini` or get them by `ini_get()` for `session_handler`,  `session_save_path`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It's storing the session if you reload the file?

```
<?php
    session_start();


   if (isset($_SESSION)) {
      print_r($_SESSION);
   } else {
      echo 'no session';
   }

    $_SESSION['test'] = 'test';
?>
```

Comment: no it is not storing the sessions even after reload. i tried the code you given it is also returning "Array ( )"

Comment: Is the Session ID stored in a cookie $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"] or do you need to pass it over to the next file?

Comment: Does it work like this? 

<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'true';
print_r($_SESSION);
?>

Comment: yes it work's like this but if in next request i remove "$_SESSION['test']" then "print_r($_SESSION);" returns empty array

Comment: So, PHP can not save the Session data in the session files. U have to check/change your configuration.